# Webdesign for beginner

Tags: mysql, laravel, web, project

I want to make a website which will serve as news aggregator site. This will be my learning project but I don't know from where to start. Should I build the front end first, or the back end first. Further I will need a database to store the jobs. Should I design my database schema before everything else. A guidance in this regard will be appreciated. For technology I will use bootstrap, laravel and mysql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Database schema is a good place to start. Once you have something in place which you think houses all of the data you will need to display everything, do some reading about database normalization and think very carefully about what you have.

Once you have a solid database design, you can start working on the code. Instead of breaking the project into frontend and backend, try to break it into features. Focus on as small a thing as you can which can function on it's own and work on the backend and front end for that feature. Initially that might be getting information about a site from which you will be aggregating news into your database. Do you have a database for those? If you, start with a form where you can submit the name and url. Once that is working, work on a page to see a list of those you have submit. Then you can start to layer in new features. Add other fields to the form for the sites. Edit them. Delete them. etc.

Comment: What typical workflow is often followed in Web development

Comment: It really varies depending on circumstances, but what I'm describing here is a good desirable workflow. By focusing in on very small pieces of functionality and seeing them through to working correctly before moving onto related features, you are able to narrow your focus to the details of that specific feature and are a lot more likely to get things right. It might be worth your time to do some reading about test driven development also. You might not want to start out trying to do test driven development, but you should be aware of it and be thinking about it in the long run.